# What does $\hat{\phi}$ mean in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors, definition, notation

When talking about the unit vectors in [cylindrical coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html), $\hat{\phi}$ often comes up. However, I cannot find a straightforward meaning for it. However, I do know that it is perpendicular to $\hat{\rho}$. How is that significant?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html

Comment: While this article is very informative, it does not give a physical explanation of ϕ^. Thank you for linking it though.

Comment: Coordinate systems aren’t physical. They are mathematical. There is no “physical explanation” of the diagram.

Comment: While that is true, my physical-sided mind wishes to have a qualitative explanation.

Comment: $\hat\phi$ points in the “tangential” direction, along the tangent to circles centered on the $z$-axis. It is perpendicular to the radial direction and the axial direction.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful.

Comment: I am glad that I helped, but it seems to me that what I described in words is merely what the diagram shows.

Comment: I will leave it to someone who wants to write an answer to explain why orthonormal bases are nice.

Comment: Are you talking about $\vec{\theta}$ as shown in the linked diagram?

Answer (score 3):

From the linked article it shows exactly what the vector $\hat{\theta}$ means

[image: pic]

There it is, a unit vector pointing around the "hoop" direction, tangent to the surface and perpendicular to the axial direction $\hat{z}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're giving a thumbs-up with your right hand with your fingers loosely curled, and your thumb is pointing along $\hat{z}$, then your other fingers are curled along $\hat{\phi}$.